# How to update recycler view (data from sqllite) without restarting the activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I have a single activity app (MainActivity) with a dialog fragment. The DialogFragment adds data to the sqllite data base and the MainActivity displays the data in a recycler view. The problem I'm facing is that when I click the "add button" in the DialogFragment and dismisses it, the newly inserted data does not get displayed in the recycler view until the activity gets recreated.

How do I display new data without restarting the app. I have already added "recyclerViewAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged" in the DialogFragment class, but it's still not working!

Comment: Add some code if you want concrete help. But in general, you'd need to reload data from database ( or have some live-data in which case observer would be notified automatically )

Comment: You can solve it by maintaining activity lifecycle method. You just override onResume() method. Put your "data fetching " code inside onResume() method and call onResume() after the data save and before the dialogfragment dismiss.

This fix your problem.  But it is not recommended. You should use viewModel, livedata.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by following activity lifecycle method. You just override `onResume()` method. Put your "data fetching" code and set your adapter inside `onResume()` method and call `onResume()` after the data save and before the DialogFragment dismiss. This fix your problem.
**But it is not recommended**. You should learn to use ViewModel, LiveData.

Example:

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvSocket).also { rv ->
            var userList : List<User> = fatchDataFromSQLite()
            rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = UserAdapter(userList)
            rv.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
```

Then call onResume() method where you save your data by button click before dismiss your DialogFragment.